CBCentralManager can't discover the device on macos?
I use Core Bluetooth Framework to discover bluetooth devices for macos APP, code as below, the variable discoveredPeripherals and print statement in centralManager callback, has no connected devices that show on my Macbook bluetooth settings, like 'Devialet Gemini II' on the image. The centralManager callback is normal, the print has print many other devices but 'Devialet Gemini II'. And I'm sure its' a BLE device.
!!! When I unpaired and disconnected the "Devialet Gemini II", can't discover the devices neither, but macos system bluetooth settings can.
system panel --(connected status img):

!!! When I unpaired and disconnected the "Devialet Gemini II", can't discover the devices neither, but macos system bluetooth settings can.
system panel--(unpaired and disconnected status img:)

print log: connected or disconnected or unpaired, always can't discover the "Devialet Gemini II" device.

class BluetoothManager: NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate, ObservableObject {
    @Published var isBluetoothEnabled = false
    @Published var discoveredPeripherals = [CBPeripheral]()
    @Published var connectedPeripherals = [CBPeripheral]()
    @Published var pairedPeripherals = [CBPeripheral]()

    private var centralManager: CBCentralManager!

    override init() {
        super.init()
        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }
    
    func connect(_ central: CBCentralManager, _ peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        central.connect(peripheral)
    }

    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        if central.state == .poweredOn {
            isBluetoothEnabled = true
            centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)  
        } else {
            isBluetoothEnabled = false
        }
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        
        // there is no connected devices(named "Devialet Gemini II") as image show !!!!!!!!!
        print("discover:  \(peripheral.name ?? "Unknown")-\(peripheral.state)")

        if !discoveredPeripherals.contains(peripheral) {
            discoveredPeripherals.append(peripheral)
        }
        if !connectedPeripherals.contains(peripheral) && peripheral.state == .connected {
            connectedPeripherals.append(peripheral)
        }
    }
}


When Bluetooth LE device is already connected it usually stops advertising (except if a device allows multiple connections, but usually BLE peripheral allows only one connection). That is why already connected device can not be discovered. The Bluetooth classic audio devices do the same as they can play audio from a single source only so once connected they remove discoverable flag and turns "advertising" off. To enumerate already connected devices you need to use retrieveConnectedPeripherals function or something like that.

When I disconnect the "Devialet Gemini II" deivce, can't discover nether, as the second image show. The other bluetooth devices that I connected multi times, can discover too. So I can't agree to you.

As an audio device it usually remembers pairing and will not be discoverable until you put it in a discoverable mode again to repair. It is common behavior for all Bluetooth audio devices. Unpair it and put in discoverable mode by pressing the button for 3 seconds (as described in the manual). You can agree or disagree or whatever else but this is how Bluetooth audio devices usually work.

When I unpaired and disconnected the "Devialet Gemini II", can't discover the devices neither, but macos system bluetooth settings can. See second image.

"put in discoverable mode by pressing the button for 3 seconds (as described in the manual)."

Yes I do the button 3 seconds. the pair light is blinking, it's pairing. Also can't discover.... By the way another earpods(MOMENTUM TW 2) I have can always discover,  whenever its' connected or disconnect.

By the way, is your device LE or Classic one? Try to check it with android. You can check it with nrfConnect app to make sure it is LE.

CoreBluetooth is only for Bluetooth low energy. The headphones are probably not using BLE. They would be using legacy Bluetooth. On macOS you can use IOBluetooth to work with these devices
